# How to list posts from categories with custom post type? (WP)

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am having an issues with custom post type.

So what I am trying to do, list all posts from subcategories while calling a main category. Usualy this worked with no problem with normal post type from Wordpress, but since I tried to use custom post type it's not working...

My category structure is like this:

- Category

  - Sub category
    ( Posts inside )
  - Sub category
    ( Posts inside )

Any help or tips are appreciated. Thanks

```
    <?php
    $categories = get_categories('title_li=&hide_empty=1&parent=1430');

    foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo "<div class='col-12' style='border-bottom: 0'><h1 class=''>".$category->name."</h1></div>";
    $args = array('cat'=> $category->term_id);
    if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <!-- article -->
        <article class="col-3">
            <div class="image">
                <span class="helper"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></a>
            </div>
            <h1><a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php the_content();?>
        </article>
        <!-- /article -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; }?>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems going on here:

First, you're not declaring a loop, or calling `get_posts`.

Second, if you check out the documentation for [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) (which is the "backbone" behind get_posts, so the arguments are essentially the same), you'll see that if you do NOT pass in an argument for [post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters), the default is `post`.

So, since you've not shared with us the post type, you'll have to adjust the below as needed:

```
// .. your code above ....

$args = array(
    'cat'=> $category->term_id, 
    // Include the post_type in the query arguments
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type' // Change this as needed 
);

// Now we need to actually query for the posts...
$custom_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
// These are modified to use our custom loop...
if ($custom_posts->have_posts() ) : while ($custom_posts->have_posts() ) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
// .. your code below ...  the_title(), etc will work here...
```

Comment: Thanks, the post type in array is the thing that was most missing, I did try add $custom_post before but eh wasn't working.